# How to validate a file extension and discard the http request if the extension is not supported

Tags: java, file-upload, webserver, multipart

I am trying to write a **webservice** class which actually handles **multipart requests**. T client will try to upload **zip or tar.gz** files which may be ***upto 1GB in size***.

I dont want to validate the extension i client side.

I want to validate the file extension in server side and discard the request before the file is uploaded.

How can I do this?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: How using `Servlet Filter` to validate your requirement in front of webservice calls??

Comment: It would help if you would add your desired web service technology.

Comment: @Smutje: We use RestEasy in jboss

Comment: @WundwinBorn: Yeah I am also looking at servlet filter. But my doubt is, when will the filter receive the request from the HTTP adapter? Will the file be uploaded to the server by the time the filter is called by the container?

Comment: @WundwinBorn I dont want the file to be uploaded to the server. Not even in a temporary directory if it is an invalid file

Comment: Do you have access to the filename from the original headers? Or can you add it on the client side? Then you can use "Expect" logic and send back 100 or 417.

Comment: Yeah I have the file name in the original headers. What is "Expect" logic?